# how to make VAT Number optional in magento 2 checkout for new customers

Tags: magento2, validation, vat, eav-attributes

[image]

> I enabled the VAT Number in Magento 2 admin
>
> **I want to make the field is optional**
>
> how i can do this??

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_ModuleName_checkout_layout_processor" type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     *
     * @param CustomerSession $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSession $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {

        if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $jsLayout = $this->addValidationRuleForVat($jsLayout,true);
        } else {
            $jsLayout = $this->addValidationRuleForVat($jsLayout);
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }

    private function addValidationRuleForVat($jsLayout, $requiredEntry = false)
    {
        if(isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['vat_id']['validation'] = [
                'required-entry' => $requiredEntry
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```